# Is this the expansion for any known function?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, power-series

The expansion is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!(n-1)!}\left[c(1+c)\dots((n-1)^2+c)\right]$$

So the first 3 terms are $cx$, $\dfrac{c(1+c)}{2}x^2$, $\dfrac{c(1+c)(4+c)}{12}x^3$.

Comment: Have you checked that it is convergent? For instance, for $c>0$, it does not seem to me convergent for any value of $x\neq 0$.

Comment: @Raskolnikov. For $x<1$, it is fine (unless I am mistaken)

Comment: @Claude_Leibovici I see you have interpreted his product as $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(c+i^2)$, whereas I interpreted it as $\prod_{i=0}^{(n-1)^2}(c+i)$. Your interpretation makes more sense of course (especially considering his first 3 terms), but you can see how ambiguous it is without proper notation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, your problem is
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!(n-1)!}\,\,\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(c+k^2)$$

Using Pochhammer symbols
$$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(c+k^2)=c \left(1-i \sqrt{c}\right)_{n-1} \left(1+i \sqrt{c}\right)_{n-1}$$

$$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(c+k^2)=\frac{\sqrt{c}\, \sinh \left(\pi  \sqrt{c}\right) }{\pi }\,\Gamma \left(n-i
   \sqrt{c}\right)\, \Gamma \left(n+i \sqrt{c}\right)$$

All the ingredients are now present to define the Gaussian hypergeometric function
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!(n-1)!}\,\,\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(c+k^2)=c\, x \,\, _2F_1\left(1-i \sqrt{c},1+i \sqrt{c};2;x\right)$$

If $a_n$ represents the summand, then
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{ \left(n^2+c\right)}{n (n+1)}x$$ which shows the radius of convergence; so, the function is defined for any $x<1$.

Comment: Maybe use a summation index $k$ instead of $i$, because it's confusing.

Comment: @Raskolnikov. For sure ! Thanks for pointing it.